# String to double or decimal

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

How to convert a string to a double or decimal? In Exact Online (REST API) I try to calculate with a decimal value in a string field. e.g `items.netprice + items.notes`. The field `items.notes` contains the decimal value. 
Tried using `cast` and `convert` in combination with `float` and `decimal`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you show what you gave got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a solution like:

```
select case
       when regexp_replace(c, '[^0-9.]', '', 1, 0, 'g') = c
       then to_number(c)
       else null
       end       
from   ( select '123.45' c
         from   dual@datadictionary
         union all
         select '123invalid.45' c
         from   dual@datadictionary
       )
```

The `case` with `regexp_replace` ensures that non-number are returned as null. You might want to change that to an error if deemed necessary.